# Custom draw a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am trying to create a UITableViewCell which overrides the complete drawing of the contents.  I have overridden drawRect, which is being called, but it still draws the default contents.

How do I get it to stop drawing the default contents and how do I replace it with my own rendering?

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

    DLog (@"Overloaded TableCell initWithStyle");
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    DLog (@"TableCell::drawRect");

    // expecting it to draw nothing
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Loren Brichter (author of Tweetie) talked about this in one of the iTunes U Stanford iPhone Programming course lectures.  He said that he had gotten great scrolling performance results by subclassing UITableViewCell and drawing the contents of each cell directly and he gives a code example in [his blog post on the subject](http://blog.atebits.com/2008/12/fast-scrolling-in-tweetie-with-uitableview/).

He also notes that apple has added [a similar example](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/TableViewSuite/index.html) in one of their code examples.

Comment: this is also always covered a ton at WWDC, if you can get the session videos.

Comment: I don't see how this response answer's the question: 'I have overridden drawRect, which is being called, but it still draws the default contents.'

Answer (score 3):

Loren Brichter's blog is no longer available. However, the code was moved here:

https://github.com/enormego/ABTableViewCell

In the hope it's a more permanent URL.

Comment: There is a snapshot of the Blog entry in the web.archive: http://web.archive.org/web/20081215081040/http://blog.atebits.com/2008/12/fast-scrolling-in-tweetie-with-uitableview/

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a subclass of UIView (with your own `drawRect`) and assign it to the table cell's `contentView` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Interface Builder to create your custom UITableViewCell?

Create your xib and then load it like this:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
cell = (MyCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nibContents objectAtIndex:0];
}

// do your customization
return cell;
```

Note that the actual cell is at index 0 in the xib.

Cheers...