# Draw rectangle in custom table cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, tablecell

How would I draw a rectangle in a custom table cell class? The cell currently has a background image with a few text labels. I would like to draw a rectangle behind each of the labels so they are easier to read over the detailed background image.

I know I could just set the background colour of the label but I would like to have padding between the background colour and the text. If that is possible, I'd love to know how! :)

I'm subclassing a TTTableMessageItemCell in Three20, a method below gets called in which you can play with subviews of the cell,

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {

[super layoutSubviews];

CGFloat padding = 16;
CGFloat boxWidth = self.contentView.width - 2*padding;
CGFloat textWidth = boxWidth - (padding*2);
CGFloat textHeight = 100;
CGFloat top = kTableCellSmallMargin;

// Position Heading Text
_titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(padding, top, textWidth, _titleLabel.font.ttLineHeight);
top += _titleLabel.height;

// Position Detail Text
[self.detailTextLabel sizeToFit];
self.detailTextLabel.top = top+2*padding;
self.detailTextLabel.left = 2*padding;
self.detailTextLabel.width = textWidth;
self.detailTextLabel.height = 100;    
}
```

I would like the rectangles to be placed behind the _titleLable and detailTextLabel labels.

**edit**
I have been able to add the right box using the following,

> ```
> UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
> view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
> view.frame = CGRectMake(padding, top, textWidth, textHeight+2*padding);
> [self insertSubview:view belowSubview:self.detailTextLabel];
> ```

It is laying on top of the label and I cant seem to get it behind it...

**edit**
I was adding the view to the wrong subview, fixed it with,

```
[[self.subviews objectAtIndex:0] insertSubview:view atIndex:0];
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106658/custom-draw-a-uitableviewcell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the labels to views and these to the cell.

You could use [`insertSubview:belowSubview:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) to add views behind your labels. With backgroundColor and the right frame they will do what you intend to.

You can also bring [detailLabel to front](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/bringSubviewToFront:)

Comment: I am overriding an existing cell class so I don't know if I can change where the labels are added...

Comment: you can remove the label form its superview and add it to the uiview. BTW: showing us your code would make it easier to help you

Comment: I didn't include code in my initial post because I didn't think it would help. I'll add it now so you can see what I'm working with

Comment: I've managed to add the box but I can't get it behind the label, I've added my new code in an edit

Comment: Got it fixed using insertSubview:view atIndex